# How to switch to a new view for macOS app

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I am creating an app for macOS and am trying to make my Log In view switch to a Sign Up view with the press of a button. A person presses the "Create Account" button, and it takes them to the Sign Up view. I would like to know how to do this.

I tried to use Navigation Link, but it did not work without NavigationView. But even with NavigationView it did not give the correct result and I don't want to use NavigationView if possible.

```
Here is the code from my Content View:

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AppViewModel
    var body: some View {
       
            Login()
       }
}

struct SignupView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AppViewModel
    var body: some View {

            Signup()
       }
}

Here is the code from my Login view:

HStack{
         Text("Don't have an account yet?")
             .foregroundColor(.gray)
         NavigationLink("Create Account", destination: SignupView())
    }
```

Comment: What is a "new view" on Mac? Do you mean a new window?

Comment: Yes, a new window. How do I connect the individual views to show a new window.